# Unable to get value from checkbox bootstrap toggle in PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Html :

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="get_ckvalue" data-toggle="toggle"  data-on="Available" data-off="Day Off" value="true" />
```

PHP Code :

```
$get_ckvalue=$_post['get_ckvalue']; 
echo $get_ckvalue;
```

I am using checkbox button with bootstrap toggle and i want to get the value (true/false) , but i am getting null as a result . i don't know what is wrong . 
How can i get the value from checkbox . 
Thank in advanced . its just the fragment of code . i have successfully submitted the POST  .

Comment: Use javascrpt instead of php. Once the page is loaded you're not gonna get anything because you aren't sending any post parameter not even a request, thats why, $_POST prints the value just the first time that you load the page.

Check the `document.querySelector('. get_ckvalue').value`

Comment: where is your submit button?

Comment: seems you need to learn the basic of php basic form.

Comment: i have submitted the form , its just  the main part of code

Comment: @kashif :- update your code first otherwise you wont get answer.

Comment: @Idir Ouhab Meskine  , its just the segment of code .  Since production all the code in not possible . i am just unable to get the value with bootstrap toggle . if i dont use the bootstrap toggle . its work fine and perfect  but give null when bootstrap toggle

Comment: @Beginner  its just the segment of code . Since production all the code in not possible . i am just unable to get the value with bootstrap toggle . if i dont use the bootstrap toggle . its work fine and perfect but give null when bootstrap toggle

Comment: HTML form submission only includes _checked_ checkboxes. If you don’t check the box, then no name=value pair will be send.

Comment: @ CBroe . I am not getting the desired result on check of the checkbox .  i am exception two result (true/null) on checked and unchecked respectively but i am getting  null in both case